# Android Billing - I receive response code 5

Tags: java, android, google-play, in-app-purchase

I had my in-app billing working, but then I moved some code around for greater extensibility and it broke. Essentially what I was trying to do was make an Adapter for my addons so that it would be easier to add them in with less programming effort later. My project has billing permissions in the manifest and is configured for billing on the Google Play Store so that's not the issue.

AdOnsActivity

```
public class AdOnsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private IInAppBillingService mService;
    private ServiceConnection mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mService = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ad_ons);

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
        serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
        bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        listAdOns = findViewById(R.id.listAdOns);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ...
                    listAdOns.setAdapter(new AdOnAdapter(AdOnsActivity.this, json.getJSONArray("adOns"), mService));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(AdOnsActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.error_load_ad_ons), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

AdOnAdapter

```
public class AdOnAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public AdOnAdapter(Activity activity, JSONArray adOns, IInAppBillingService mService) throws RemoteException {
        Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();

        this.activity = activity;
        this.adOns = adOns;
        this.mService = mService;

        skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3, activity.getPackageName(), "inapp", querySkus);
        responseDetails = skuDetails.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
        ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, activity.getPackageName(), "inapp", null);
        responseOwned = ownedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

All the response codes [are listed here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html).

5 means you are calling the API with invalid arguments. You have broken your API call somehow. Maybe compare the contents of your API call under the old and new version of your code (you are using source control right?).

- **0.** BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK:  Success
- **1.** BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_USER_CANCELED: User pressed back or canceled a dialog
- **2.** BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE: Network connection is down
- **3.** BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE: Billing API version is not supported for the type requested
- **4.** BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_UNAVAILABLE: Requested product is not available for purchase
- **5.** BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR: Invalid arguments provided to the API. This error can also indicate that the application was not correctly signed or properly set up for In-app Billing in Google Play, or does not have the necessary permissions in its manifest
- **6.** BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ERROR: Fatal error during the API action
- **7.** BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED: Failure to purchase since item is already owned
- **8.** BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_NOT_OWNED: Failure to consume since item is not owned

Comment: Which arguments would I need to consider? Just `getSkuDetails()` (the function throwing the error) or other functions too?

Comment: The error just says that the function which sends the RPC to Play has incorrect arguments, so yes, getSkuDetails() if that is the result with an error.

Answer (score 1):

This error can be a bunch of things according to the documentation. For me it was the Licensed users. When I was adding them, there wasn't an indication that the emails were being added to the list of licence testers. I kept adding them, chaging the "License response" and saving but nothing changed at all.

It was after a while that I realize that I had to press "Enter" in the email list to actually add the users. I know it sounds silly but that was my only issue (at least I think it was since I spend a day searching for the cause).

So, if you getting this error and don't see any emails inside `Settings -> License Testing -> License testers` you might be a single key of distance of getting your debug working properly.

Answer (score 0):

"response code 5  Obfuscated profile id cannot be set without obfuscated account id." It was my error. And after checking I've found my `setObfuscatedAccountId` is empty. Also Or it could be any other param that you provided to billing client.